# No network devices available ubuntu budgie 19.04

Tags: networking, 19.04, ubuntu-budgie

After installing Ubuntu budgie 19.04. I can not connect to the internet. No network devices available. I googling a lot but currently I dont have internet, so I cannot try any approach to fix this issue.

The output of `lshw -C network` show the RTL8821CE WiFi Driver.

What should I do? I tried to reinstall Ubuntu 19.04 but nothing happened.
Please help!